# how to detect an orientation change in Corona SDK on Android for an Landscape Only app?

Tags: android, coronasdk, orientation-changes

How to detect an orientation change in Corona SDK on Android for an Landscape Only app?

I note that the following do not work:

- using the orientation event won't work - this is noting an orientation event is not produced when switching between landscapeLeft to landscapeRight or vice-versa (i.e. portrait not supported in the app)
- using the "resize" event doesn't work - it only occurs for apps that support both portrait and landscape orientations

MAIN QUESTION THEREFORE:  How to detect an orientation change in Corona SDK on Android for an Landscape Only app?

UPDATE:  Actually some concerning is that I've just confirmed that on Android (on my new Nexus 7) that "system.orientation" is NOT changes when I tip the device upside down.  That is it stay on "landscapeRight".  So would this be a Corona bug?   Only fix is going to be not allowing users to be able to tip/use the game upside down then no?  (i.e. in landscapeLeft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corona won't distinguish between landscapeLeft and landscapeRight if your app only supports landscape mode. The Docs for Project Build Settings (http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html) state that:

> 4.In Android 2.2, if you build a landscape-only app by supporting landscapeRight and landscapeLeft, it will never display in the
>   landscapeLeft mode. Likewise, if you build a portrait-only app by
>   supporting portrait and portraitUpsideDown, it will never appear as
>   portraitUpsideDown. This is an Android 2.2 limitation.

I've created a small project and can confirm that on my Nexus4 with Android 4.3, "orientation" event too doesn't get called (although it works in Simulator).

To answer your questions then: you can't detect orientation change for landscape only app. It doesn't seem to be Corona bug, rather Android limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently on Android devices, orientation events are only generated when auto-rotation is enabled in the build.settings file.